# How can I get a laptop's Windows 10 taskbar to show the battery level?

Tags: laptop, windows-10, battery, taskbar

I've done searches with various permutations of battery life, power level, etc., and all the web content I've been able to see so far has been information on how to use power plans and other decisions that influence battery life, but not a symbol on the taskbar telling how full or empty the battery life is.

I'm not sure if I've missed the one word I should have additionally been searching for, but what (if any) options does Windows 10 provide to have the taskbar tell battery life?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Right-click an empty area on the taskbar, and then tap or click Properties
2. Navigate to **Taskbar tab** > **Notification Area** and *click* **Customize...**
3. *Select* **Turn system icons on or off**
4. Under Behaviors, *select* **On** next to Power then *click* **OK**

That should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

**For Windows 10.**

1. Left-click on the up arrow on the taskbar (show hidden icons)
2. Click and hold on the battery icon and drag it to the taskbar
   The battery icon should now always be shown.

Comment: This is the shortest method to get what you want. I'd rather have this intuitive method to the accepted answer ;)